# Live sass compiler не отображается в vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

При установке этого расширения снизу должно быть написано whatch sass, как на скрине[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmVwi.jpg), а у меня[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vehiA.jpg) этого нет. Пробовала устанавливать другие версии (из доступных самая ранняя - 4.0). В курсах которые я смотрю используют 3.0.0 версию, щас она недоступна. Что делать - вообще без понятия. Гуглить пробовала, такой проблемы что даже надписи не появляется ни у кого не нашла
Может кто знает в чём дело?

Comment: У меня установленно [данное расширение](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass) и оно прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 0):

Я установил Live Server, не знаю, пока как он работает до конца, но вроде также, как и сас.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + shift + P

В поиске "Watch Sass" и выбираете смотреть

Answer (score 0):

Нужно после установки расширения создать папку sass и в ней файл в формате .scss и открыть его. Тогда внизу на панели появится значок Watch Sass

Answer (score 0):

В той строке, что у Вас на скрине, попробуйте нажать правой кнопкой и посмотреть на список отображаемых расширений. у меня было установлено много галочек на отображение расширений и watch sass просто не был виден из-за других включенных приложений. Попробуйте поотжимать галочки ненужных состояний. А заодно и проверить, есть ли вообще у вас в списке watch sass

Answer (score 0):

Была та же проблема, никакие из описанных способов не помогли. Разобрался буквально 10 минут назад: установил предыдущую версию расширения и волшебным образом кнопка "Watch Sass" появилась. Последняя актуальная версия 6.1.2, я установил 6.1.1.